# Powerpoint (or Word): search by regex, change text color

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, microsoft-powerpoint, colors

I have a block of text that looks like this:

```
0000000000000000 N=5955 VAL=  0.24  0.53  0.53  0.53  1.05
0000000000000001 N=2387 VAL=  0.13  0.53  0.53  0.53  0.53
0000000000000010 N=72248 VAL=  0.05  0.53  0.53  0.53  4.65
0000000000000011 N=12915 VAL=  0.06  0.53  0.53  0.53  2.10
```

The initial rows represent a bit decomposition, and I wish to highlight specific bits (say, bits 8 & 9) with a different color. I know how to select the relevant characters with a regular expression, but I don't know how to use that to change the color. Any tips?

Comment: How did you search in Word? You can use Replace feature in Word to find the target bits then replace it with formatted bits.  Click Replace in Word to open Find and Replace window, under Replace tab, fill in the Find field and Replace filed. Under Replace option, select Font, set specific color for replaced word. https://imgur.com/a/JWHa4g9

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll always want to act on specific character positions within the string, this snippet of VBA will do it for you in PPT:

```
Option Explicit

' Edit these as needed to control where the color change starts/stops
Const lStartChar As Long = 2
Const lNumChars As Long = 4

    Sub ChangeFontColor()
    ' This assumes that you've selected the text you want to operate on

        With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Characters(lStartChar, lNumChars)
            .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With

    End Sub
```